# Matlab's built in function calllib is very slow

Tags: c, matlab, dll

I have a code in C implemented in visual studio 2017.

I have created dll for this code in order to run it in Matlab's environment (to enjoy visualization of Matlab) using Matlab's built in function calllib.

The way I've created the dll is based on the fibbonachi example of:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=vs-2017

Now when I run my code in visual studio environment it takes about 2 seconds whereas in Matlab it takes about 40 seconds. Is this common? Is there an alternative way to run a c code using Matlab and make it as fast as in C?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/introducing-mex-files.html

Comment: Is implementation using mex expected to be faster than using Matlab's built in function calllib?

Comment: Yes, much faster. If you really have a 38 second delay calling this function through `calllib`, then the MEX-file will be about 38 seconds faster. There should not be a perceivable delay calling a MEX-file.